# Groups and prime numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $ (G,\cdot ) $ be a group, $ p>2 $ a prime number, and $ a,b \in G, a,b\neq e $ so that $ a^{p}=b^{2}=e $ and $ b\cdot a=a^{p-1}\cdot b. $ Prove that:

a) If $ i,j \in \mathbb{Z},a^{i} \cdot b^{j}=e \Leftrightarrow p|i $ and $ 2|j. $

b) $ H=\left \{ a^{i}b^{j}|i,j\in \mathbb{Z} \right \} $ is a subgroup of $ G $ with $ |H|=2p $.

In a), the $ "\Leftarrow " $ is obvious, but what should I do next?

Comment: I sense a typo in "$b \cdot a = a^{p-1} = b$" as that currently implies $a = 1$. Perhaps it should just be $ba = a^{p - 1}b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a^ib^j = e$ then $a^i = e$ if $j$ is even, so $p | i$. If, on the other hand $j$ is odd then $(a^ib^j)^p = e \iff a^{ip}b^{jp} = e \iff b^{jp} = e$, a contradiction since $jp$ is odd.